# Как сделать повторный ввод с клавиатуры и сократить код Java?

Tags: java

метод `numCheckEquals` принимает 4 целых цифр с консоли a,b,c,d. В цикле for я отправляю в метод `numCheckEquals` 4 цифр с консоли, и каждый раз пишу `sc.nextInt();` а что если программа требует 100 цифр, представьте какой огромный код будет. как сократить эти `sc.nextInt();`

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(Solution.checkNumEquals(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: вот это что такое? ``(int i = sc.nextInt(); i <= 4; i++) ``

Comment: исправил там 0 стоит

Comment: Ну так сассивы используй.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

принимаем значения в бесконечном цикле...

```
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                int nextInt = console.nextInt();
    
                System.out.println(nextInt);
                if (nextInt == -1) // условие выхода
                    break;
```

также стоит ознакомиться c `Varargs` — это аргументы переменной длины, позволяющие нам создавать методы с произвольным количеством аргументов.

```
public class Solution {
         static void varArgs(int... nums) {
             for (int num : nums) {
                 System.out.print(num);
             }
             System.out.println();
         }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        varArgs(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
        varArgs(1,2,3,4);
        varArgs(5,6,7,8,9);

    }
}
```

либо читай про метод hasNext

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355062/how-to-use-hasnext-from-the-scanner-class

Comment: Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: пожалуйста... если ответ был полезен, можно поставить "плюс" возле ответа.